# Cannot get CSS item

Tags: html, css, nokogiri

I ran into difficulty getting a radio schedule from http://www.franceculture.fr/programmes#/2014-01-26

My code is:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'nokogiri'  
require 'open-uri' 
file=File.open('/Users/hubertus/Dropbox/Apps/Drafts/radio/franceculture-2014-01-29-17-10- 34.txt', 'r')
url=file.readline
target=file.readline

f = File.open('/Users/hubertus/Desktop/output.txt', 'w') 

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
doc.css(".actionnable").each do |item|  
#puts item
heure = item.at_css(".plage").text 
text = item.at_css("a").text 
description = item.at_css(':nth-child(3)').text
link =item.at_css('a')[:href]

f.puts "#{heure} - #{text} -#{description} - #{link}"  
end 
f.close
namesarr=File.read('/Users/hubertus/Desktop/output.txt').split(/\n/)
puts namesarr.select{ |i| i < target }.max
file.close
```

I want to get the later CSS items, as in the following HTML, I would like to get the second link (href:/emission-un-autre-jour-est-possible-pixar-%C2%AB-25-ans- d%E2%80%99animation-exposition-metamorphoses-de-la-foret-)
and its title (Pixar « 25 ans d’animation  " exposition m de la for guyanaise : s>Pixar « 25 ans d’animation  "Exposition / Métamorphoses de la forêt guyanaise  : série)

```
<li class="actionnable">
<span class="plage">06:00</span>
<h2><a href="/emission-un-autre-jour-est-possible-0" title="Un autre jour est possible ">Un autre jour est possible </a></h2>

<p> Production : Tewfik Hakem.  Réalisation : Thomas Dutter. </p>
<img src="/sites/all/themes/franceculture/images/down.png" width="20" height="20"  alt="déplier/replier" class="action"><ul>
  <li>
  <span>06:00</span><a href="/emission-un-autre-jour-est-possible-pixar-%C2%AB-25-ans- d%E2%80%99animation-exposition-metamorphoses-de-la-foret-" title="Pixar « 25 ans d’animation  " exposition m de la for guyanaise : s>Pixar « 25 ans d’animation  "Exposition / Métamorphoses de la forêt guyanaise  : série</a>
  <p>
  </p>
  </li>
    </ul>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
  </li>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get this with CSS selectors?

Comment: Is your file really named `"/Users/hubertus/Dropbox/Apps/Drafts/radio/franceculture-2014-01-29-17-10-        34.txt"`, with multiple spaces in it?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake, corrected